# AWS Windows Server with FSx connected to DC problem with RDP NLA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, amazon-fsx, nla

Just quick basics: Everything in in the same VPC and subnet. Security groups and ACLs are correct (based on aws documentation).
Now... I've got Windows Server 2019 EC2 instance with Domain Controller. I used that DC to create FSx for Windows.

Then I attached that FSx to different Windows Server 2019 EC2 instance with configured IIS on it. Let's call it template. With that template I created AMI to use for autoscaling.

Unfortunately since I launched 3 instances I'm no longer able to log in to them via RDP. I can RDP only to DC. I can't RDP to template or any of 3 instances launched from created AMI. 
I've got and error: 
[image]

Most of suggested solutions are not applicable because I can't RDP to EC2 instance. Is there a way to do it remotely from DC? Or anything? In worst case I'll recreate environment again but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: How did you created the AMI? Did you sysprep the Instance before creating the AMI?

Comment: No. From EC2 console -> Actions -> Image -> Create Image.

Comment: Before creating the image try to sysprep the Image using EC-2 Launch and then use it to duplicate your infra.